# Sort a data.frame to column

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a question regarding the use of the function order (), I have the following data.frame and I am using the following statement but I can not sort the column, and can not find the error. I want this column Tag_PHASE ordered from lowest to highest.

```
    Tag_PHASE   Num_EPC
1   101.0   1
2   126.0   1
3   70.0    1
4   73.0    1
5   78.0    3
6   81.0    1
7   84.0    1
8   87.0    1
9   90.0    1
10  92.0    3

a<-DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter[order(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Tag_PHASE), ]
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It does not give me any errors ... just does not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt:

```
DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter <- 
   data.frame(Tag_PHASE = runif(10)*100, Num_EPC = sample(c(1,3), 10,prob = c(.7,.3), replace = T))
DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter

DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter[order(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Tag_PHASE),]
```

Note: You are assigning the results to a:

```
a <- DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter[order(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter$Tag_PHASE),]
```

So to see the results you'll have to print a

```
a
```

Here is a simpler way to do this:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(DF_TAG_PHASE_EPC_counter)
DT[order(Tag_PHASE)]
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r/10758086#10758086)